# fetch values of radiobutton list of primary key table to another foreign key table using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server-2008

I have created two tables in a SQL Server database and a RadioButtonList in an ASP.NET page. In one table I have stored values for each radio button as primary key. I want that on clicking that radio button, its primary key value in stored another table in a foreign key column.

Here I am using store procedure in MS-SQl. 
primary key table is gender and foreign key table is user.In aspx page i dm dispalying gender as radiobuttons, now the question is how can i fetch primary id of gender table and fill in users table.My code is as below:

```
ArrayList arSample = new ArrayList();
Object[] n_gender_id = new Object[3] { "@intGender", "Int", (rbtngender.SelectedValue != "") ? rbtngender.SelectedValue : "" };
```

I am getting values of radiobutton how get ids of particular button.
help out.......

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to do something like `SELECT [Id] FROM [user] WHERE [gender] = @intGender` and set the value of @intGender to be the selected radio button value.

Since the parameter you've shown appears to be an integer, I'd probably start with something like:

```
var arSample = new ArrayList();
int gender;
if (!int.TryParse(rbtngender.SelectedValue, out gender)) return;

using (var conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionStringNameFromWeb.Config"].ConnectionString))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand("storedProcName", conn))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@intGender", gender);

        conn.Open();
        using (SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (dr.Read())
            {
                // process each row from the data reader...
                arSample.Add(dr["Id"]);
            }
        }
        conn.Close();
    }
}
```